# SCCM 2012 Client will not pick up site

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012, sccm-2007

I am working on migrating SCCM 2007 to 2012.

I have the server setup, AD configured for the new server, and everything is working except for the clients.  The 2012 client will not connect to my 2012 site.  I get:

```
<![LOG[LSGetSiteVersionFromAD : Successfully retrieved version '4.00.6487.0000' for site     'MCS']LOG]!>
<![LOG[LSIsSiteVersionCompatible : Site Version '4.00.6487.0000' is not compatible.]LOG]!>
<![LOG[LSIsSiteCompatible : Site <MCS> Version '4.00.6487.0000' is not compatible.]LOG]!>
```

I get the above errors even when trying to manually assign the site. I do not have overlapping boundaries for the sites.

What's weird is that neither of my sites are version 4.00.6487.0000.  My 2007 site is version 4.00.6487.2000.

**Where is it that the clients pick up the site version numbers?**  Is there anything that I can do to fix this, without removing my 2007 site from AD?

Comment: Is 'MCS' your 2012 site code or your 2007 site code?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out someone else in our AD forest (largest AD deployment in the world) was already using MCS.  I had to start over with a new site code, but everything is working as it should now.